# sscanf %u not intepreting hexadecimal

Tags: c, c99, scanf, iar

I'm trying to convert from hexadecimal or decimal text to an unsigned int using the "%u" format specifier of `sscanf`.  The result is not correct, for the value 0x01, `sscanf` is returning a 0 (0).

According to [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf), the definition of "%u" specifier (highlighting is mine):
i, u    Integer Any number of digits, optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).
Decimal digits assumed by default (0-9), but a 0 prefix introduces octal digits (0-7), **and 0x hexadecimal digits (0-f)**.

According to Harbison & Steele, 3rd Edition:
**The u conversion**  Unsigned decimal conversion is performed.
...
The format of the number read is the same as expected for the input to the `strtol` function with the value 10 for the `base` argument; that is a sequence of decimal digits optionally preceded by - or +.

Note that one of the definitions allows "0x" to be specified in the string.

I am using IAR EW compiler with the compilation set to C99 dialect.

Which definition is correct for C99?

I am receiving two different results in the following program.

Here is a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    const char text[] = "0x01 1";
    unsigned int first_value = 0U;
    unsigned int second_value = 0U;
    signed int   arguments_satisfied = 0;
    arguments_satisfied = sscanf(text, "%u %u", &first_value, &second_value);
    printf("Arguments scanned: %d, first: %d, second: %d\n",
        arguments_satisfied, first_value, second_value);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Another reason (if that were necessary) to not rely on cplusplus.com. Without trying the wayback machine, I traced the specification "u/d are decimal; x is hex; o is octal; i is general" for scanf formats back to posix 5 (1997): http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html, but I'm sure it goes back further than that. http://en.cppreference.com/w/ is better but when in doubt, the standard is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the current C standard, C11, 7.21.6.2/12, only `%i` deduces the base from the context, all other specifiers fix the base:

> `i` Matches an optionally signed integer, whose format is the same as expected
>   for the subject sequence of the `strtol` function with the **value 0 for the
>   `base`** argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed
>   integer.
>
> `o` Matches an optionally signed octal integer, whose format is the same as
>   expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the **value 8
>   for the `base`** argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.
>
> `u` Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
>   expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the **value 10
>   for the `base`** argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.
>
> `x` Matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer, whose format is the same
>   as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the **value
>   16 for the `base`** argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.